# How to copy MySQL Database from Linux server to Windows Server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, drupal

First of all, I am newbie in php and drupal. So please forgive me.
We are having a website database - "MySQL" which is on Linux Server. I don't have any access of that server or database.

I want to copy that database in my local computer which is Windows based.

What are the software requirements and what code I need to run to copy that database

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: How do you intend to copy the database if you don't have access to it?

Comment: You need access to the DB first. And Xampp / Wampp on your local computer.

Comment: @Epodax I appreciate the time you gave to me and for your response, thanks brother. Once I get the access, what will be process? Can you please suggest me?

Comment: @andre3wap Thank you so much brother, what should I do after I get the access? Thanks for your concern

Comment: If you have FTP access or your drupal site is set to allow you installation of modules (ftp account is set) then you can install module "Backup & Migrate" and use it to make database dump. https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Answer (score 3):

1. you must ask the provider or the server administrator to export that database, and to send it to you

   - he can export it using the following command

> $ mysqldump --opt -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]

- if you have the server's access credentials (ip, database username or pass) you can use workbench to access the database and export it yourself (but if you are a newbie i wouldn't recommend it)

  2. on your windows computer you must install an Apache server (i prefer xampp, but there are many others)
  3. start the service and access http://localhost/phpmyadmin
  4. use the import button to import the database. if you get the "No database selected error", first create the database and then import the file, in the newly created database

Comment: Laura Bot, ohh great!! So nice of you. Thank you soo much Laura. I appreciate your time!!